# Como fazer um input digitar dentro do outro?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Olá sou novato aqui e eu estou com uma grande dúvida...
Estou com este código:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Este campo é diretamente automático</h2>
<input type="text" id="a"> oninput: <input type="text" id="a-1"><br><br>

<script>
/*Aqui é o campo 1*/
window.oninput = function(){
document.querySelector('#a-1').value = document.querySelector('#a').value;
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

e eu gostaria de saber.. quando eu digito no primeiro campo o segundo é automaticamente preenchido mas quando vou apagar dentro do primeiro campo o segundo é apagado certo? mas se desse para fazer as mesmas coisas no segundo campo? é possível? se sim.. como?

Comment: Me desculpe estou aprendendo kkk comecei hj...perdão.. eu já fui na area de ajuda mas não estava sendo muito bem informado

Comment: mantenha o código escrito em vez do print

Comment: Me desculpa mas eu fiz isso e um dos moderadores apagaram ai eu mandei print

Comment: Não pode colocar "RESOLVIDO" na pergunta. Marcando ✔ na resposta que resolveu o problema, a pergunta será tida como resolvida.

Comment: Ahh certo Muito Obrigado :D

Comment: Vc pode marcar ✔ em apenas 1 resposta, a que achou mais útil. Se não sabe como fazer isso, dê uma olhada no [tour].

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usando `event.target.id` você consegue saber qual o `id` do campo digitado que disparou o evento `oninput` e selecionar qual campo deve ser alterado, bastando para tal inverter a ordem no `else`:

```js
window.oninput = function(event){
   
   var campo = event.target.id; // pega o id do campo que chamou o evento
   
   if(campo == "a"){
      document.querySelector('#a-1').value = document.querySelector('#a').value;
   }else if(campo == "a-1"){
      document.querySelector('#a').value = document.querySelector('#a-1').value;
   }
};
```

```html
<h2>Este campo é diretamente automático</h2>
<input type="text" id="a"> oninput: <input type="text" id="a-1"><br><br>
```

### Usando jQuery

Com jQuery você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```js
$("#a, #a-1").on("input", function(){
   var alvo = this.id == "a" ? "a-1" : "a";
   $("#"+alvo).val( this.value );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>Este campo é diretamente automático</h2>
<input type="text" id="a"> oninput: <input type="text" id="a-1"><br><br>
```

Comment: Muiito Obrigado :D

Answer (score 3):

Voce pode fazer do seguinte modo

```js
$("#a-1").bind('input',function(event) {

       var data=$(this).val();
       $("#a").val(data);
});

$("#a").bind('input',function(event) {
      
       var data=$(this).val();
       $("#a-1").val(data);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Este campo é diretamente automático</h2>
<input type="text" id="a"> oninput: <input type="text" id="a-1"><br><br>


</body>
</html>
```

Ou assim, sendo que assim se o utilizador mudar o texto sem usar
este não é detectado

```js
$("#a-1").keyup(function(event) {

       var data=$(this).val();
       $("#a").val(data);
});

$("#a").keyup(function(event) {
      
       var data=$(this).val();
       $("#a-1").val(data);
});
```

```html
  
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Este campo é diretamente automático</h2>
<input type="text" id="a"> oninput: <input type="text" id="a-1"><br><br>


</body>
</html>
```

Ou alternativa ao **bind** pois foi descontinuado nas novas versões do jQuery

> As of jQuery 3.0, .bind() has been deprecated.

Referido na [documentação](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

```js
$("#a-1").on('input',function(event) {

       var data=$(this).val();
       $("#a").val(data);
});

$("#a").on('input',function(event) {
      
       var data=$(this).val();
       $("#a-1").val(data);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Este campo é diretamente automático</h2>
<input type="text" id="a"> oninput: <input type="text" id="a-1"><br><br>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado :D

Comment: O keyup só é ruim porque não funciona se o cara colar o texto com o mouse :D... mas isso não é tão importante.

Comment: @Sam Não tinha pensado nisso

Comment: @Sam Obrigado eu coloquei outra versão de modo a evitar isso

Comment: Só cuidado que o `.bind` ficou obsoleto a partir da versão 3.0 do jQuery, ou seja, daqui a pouco será removido numa versão mais nova.

Comment: @Sam coloquei mais uma versão

Comment: Complicado.. ^^ eu testei mas não entendi muito mas os códigos do Sam eu entendi de boa ^^ Obrigado :D